# How to use GitHub SCIM filter?

Tags: github, scim

I tried to search for a GitHub SCIM User using the [filter parameter](https://developer.github.com/v3/scim/#parameters). I tried `filter=emails eq xxx4@test` or `filter=emails%20eq%20\"xxx4@test.com\"`, but it returns:

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"
    ],
    "status": 400,
    "scimType": "invalidFilter",
    "detail": "Only single 'eq' operators are supported."
}
```

When I use the filter `filter=emails%20eq%20%22xxxx@test.com%22`, it returns:

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse"
    ],
    "totalResults": 0,
    "itemsPerPage": 0,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "Resources": []
}
```

I have checked that the User whose email is `xxx4@test.com` is indeed in GitHub.

Comment: `emails` is probably a multi-value attribute?! Did you try `emails co xxx4@test.com` or `emails.value eq xxx4@test.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `filter=emails eq "xxx4@test"`.